# I ran gem clean, and now rails app won't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

so I ran
gem clean

then:
bundle install

and now my app won't start,
no error messages nothing...

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try deleting your gemfile.lock and then run bundle install again.
2. launch the rails server one more time.
3. ctrl-c to quit the function if it's stalled with no response
4. run $ tail -f log/development.log

open that file and see what went wrong, and share here.

Comment: I ended up restoring from a site backup. I couldn't afford to have my site down for too long....